# Como usar dados de um Array sem foreach

Tags: php, array, foreach

Eu tenho uma função na minha `Model`:

```
public function get_learning_category_list() {

    $categorias = $this->db->select('t1.id, t1.title, t1.metadata, t1.meta_title, t1.description, t1.meta_description, t1.meta_spam, t1.url, t1.alt_img')
        ->from('learning_category t1')
        ->join('learning_rel_category t4', 't1.id = t4.category_id', 'left')
        ->join('learning t2', 't4.learning_id = t2.id', 'left')
        ->join('learning_rel_language t3', 't2.id = t3.learning_id', 'left')
        ->where('t3.language', $this->language)
        ->group_by('t1.id')
        ->get()->result_array();

    foreach ($categorias as $c) {

        $total = $this->db->select('count(learning_rel_language.learning_id) as total', false)
            ->from('learning')
            ->join('learning_rel_language', 'learning.id = learning_rel_language.learning_id', 'inner')
            ->join('learning_rel_category', 'learning.id = learning_rel_category.learning_id', 'inner')
            ->where('learning_rel_category.category_id', $c['id'])
            ->where('learning_rel_language.language', $this->language)
            ->group_by('learning_rel_language.language')->get()->first_row('array');

        $metadata = json_decode($c['metadata']);
        $tt = $c['title'];
        $url = $c['url'];

        if ($this->language != 'pt_br') {
            $tt = $metadata->{$this->language};
            $tt_pt_br = $c['title'];
        }

        $return[] = array('url' => $url, 'title'=>$tt, 'id'=>$c['id'], 'total'=>$total['total'], 'title_pt_br'=>$tt_pt_br);
    }

    return $return; //$categorias;
}
```

Ela me resulta em um `Array` com a lista de *learnings*:

```
Array (  
    [0] => Array (  
        [url] =>  
        [title] => Cursos sobre como gerar leads qualificados  
        [id] => 2  
        [total] => 6  
        [title_pt_br] =>  
    )  
    [1] => Array (  
        [url] =>  
        [title] => Cursos de Social Media Marketing  
        [id] => 3  
        [total] => 2  
        [title_pt_br] =>  
    )  
    [2] => Array (  
        [url] =>  
        [title] => Cursos de SEO e otimização de sites  
        [id] => 4  
        [total] => 3  
        [title_pt_br] =>  
    )  
)
```

Mas eu preciso usar os dados dessas *learnings*, o `title`, `id`, etc, em outra função na `Model`:

```
public function url_format_category($category, $lang_domin) {

    if (lang('abbr') == 'en_US')
        $lang_domin = 'en/';
    else if (lang('abbr') == 'es_US')
        $lang_domin = 'es/';

    $categorias = $this->learn->get_learning_category_list();
    print_r($categorias);

    foreach ($categorias as $cat) {

        print_r($cat);
        $cat = (object) $cat;

        if ($cat->title != '') {
            $return = strtolower(url_title($cat->title)).'-cmdo-'.$cat->id;
        }
        else {
            $return = 'cursos-de-marketing-digital-online-'.$cat->id;
        }   
        return $return;   
    } 
}
```

Estou fazendo uma função para ver se a url do site está correta. Essa função (url_format_category) irá definir o formato da url, que no caso seria (O title).'-cmdo-'.(O id) Então o que eu preciso é recuperar o title e o id de acordo com a learning que se encontra.

Eu fiz assim, mas com o `foreach` sempre resulta nos mesmos dados independente de qual página eu esteja.

Como posso usar os dados desse `Array` sem o `foreach`?

Comment: Você tem um `return` dentro de um `foreach`!?

Comment: Sim, sei que está errado. Estou começando a programar a pouco tempo. Sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Eu não entendi seu problema. Coloque um exemplo do resultado que você quer obter

Comment: Eu preciso utilizar os dados do Array dentro de outra função. Mas com o foreach ele pega sempre os dados do último item do Array.

Comment: Você percebeu que tem um *array* dentro de outro? E portanto preciso de um `foreach` dentro de outro?

Comment: @bigown Não tem alguma maneira de utilizar esses dados sem o foreach?

Comment: Jeito tem, mas a melhor forma é esta. Não entendi porque essa obsessão em não usar o `foreach`.

Comment: Vou te explicar todo meu objetivo para ficar mais claro. O que estou fazendo é uma função para ver se a url do site está correta, essa função (url_format_category)  irá definir o formato da url, que no caso seria (O title).'-cmdo-'.(O id) Então o que eu preciso é recuperar o title e o id de acordo com a learning que se encontra. Entende?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fera, você pode procurar dentro do seu array em conjunto com as funções `array_search` e `array_column` (Essa função apenas para a versão igual ou superior a do PHP 5.5.0 e caso esteja usando uma hospedagem habilite essa versão caso disponível).

Acredito que você consiga adaptar seu código com essa solução.

Para sua função, imagino que você utilize slugs (urls únicas e amigáveis), então segue um exemplo abaixo do exemplo nos comentários do manual do PHP.

```
// Buscar o nome do usuário com uid == 40489
<?php 
      $array = array(
                     array(
                           'uid' => '100',
                           'name' => 'Sandra Shush',
                           'url' => 'urlof100'
                      ),
                      array(
                            'uid' => '5465',
                            'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
                            'url' => 'urlof100'
                      ),
                      array(
                            'uid' => '40489',
                            'name' => 'Michael',
                            'url' => 'urlof40489'
                       )
               );

$key = array_search(40489, array_column($array, 'uid')); /*A partir do $array, retorna um array com a coluna 'uid' e dentro desse array, procura o valor 40489 e armazena o índice do array externo na variável $key. */

if($key != null && !empty($key)) // se não estiver vazio essa chave, pesquise direto.
    echo $array[$key]['name'];
else
    echo "sem dados";
```

**http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#Hcom116635**

http://ideone.com/NcNzkl

Answer (score 1):

GWER, se você quer que o $return devolva todos o valos atribuidos a variavel é só concatenar
exemplo 
$return.= 
dai você devolve ou imprime depois do foreach a variavel se isso que você quer

exemplo:

```
public function url_format_category($category, $lang_domin) {
if (lang('abbr') == 'en_US')
    $lang_domin = 'en/';
else if (lang('abbr') == 'es_US')
    $lang_domin = 'es/';

$categorias = $this->learn->get_learning_category_list();
print_r($categorias);
foreach($categorias as $cat){
    print_r($cat);
    $cat = (object) $cat;
    if($cat->title != '') {

        //concatena  
        $return.= strtolower(url_title($cat->title)).'-cmdo-'.$cat->id;
    }else{
        //concatena  
        $return.= 'cursos-de-marketing-digital-online-'.$cat->id;
    }   

}
return $return; ou echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Resolve parte do meu problema, mas eu preciso pegar um valor especifico, não todos

Comment: entendo qual seria o valor do foreach que você quer pegar?

Comment: Vou te explicar todo meu objetivo para ficar mais claro. O que estou fazendo é uma função para ver se a url do site está correta, essa função irá definir o formato da url, que no caso seria `(O title).'-cmdo-'.(O id)` Então o que eu preciso é recuperar o title e o id de acordo com a learning que se encontra. Entende?

Comment: #GWER vamos por parte voce quer verificar se esta correto o que nesta sua rotina qual a variavel seria para verificar se esta correta url? ta meio confuso eu nao sei se voce que validar url para depois formatar ou quer formatar para depois validar, vê se eu to perto do que você quer

Comment: Eu formato ela, depois valido

Comment: o resultado final desta formtacao seria algo assim: "http://domain/[title]-cmdo-id" assim? iniciando com http://?

Comment: domain/[title]-cmdo-[id]

Comment: Acabei de solucionar este caso (com ajuda da sua resposta inclusive). Pode dar uma olhada nesta pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57496/fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-model-controller

Comment: blz cara desde já parabéns vou ver