# Funções - Model, Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, funções

Na minha model tenho esta função que define o formato da url :

```
 public function url_format_category($category, $lang_domin) {
    if (lang('abbr') == 'en_US')
        $lang_domin = 'en/';
    else if (lang('abbr') == 'es_US')
        $lang_domin = 'es/';

    if (is_array($category))  
        $category = (object) $category; 

    if($category->title != '') {
        $return = strtolower(url_title($category->title)).'-cmdo-'.$category->id;
    }else{
        $return = 'cursos-de-marketing-digital-online-'.$category->id;
    }   

    return $return;   
}
```

E na Controller tenho a função que verifica se a url está certa e redireciona se estiver errada :

```
if($this->uri->uri_string != $this->learn->url_format_category($data['category'], $lang_domin)) {
 redirect($this->learn->url_format_category($data['category'], $lang_domin),'location','301');
exit;
 }
```

Porém agora tenho que fazer a mesma coisa com um url que não contém uma Model, então queria saber se eu posso criar essas duas funções na Controller (juntas ou separadas) e como poderia fazer isso. É possível?

Obs: estou utilizando o CodeIgniter.

Comment: Model validando URL? Não compreendi o que está acontecendo nesse código...

Comment: @PapaCharlie Na model apenas está definindo o formato padrão da url. A validação é feita na Controller

Comment: Mas validação de URL é feita pela `router`. Você está se referindo à formatação dos links para a composição da view?

Comment: Isso mesmo, para a view

Comment: Bom, então eu recomendaria remover da model e transformar em um helperpara ser usado direto pela view. Não vejo esse método como parte de um model, vejo como parte do escopo de um model.

Comment: Eu poderia fazer uma junção dessas funções na Controller?

Comment: O if verifica se a Url está no formato igual definido pela model, e se ele não estiver ele redireciona para a url correta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22675/discussion-between-papa-charlie-and-gwer).

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a solução mais simples no seu caso é criar uma Model e manter o padrão que tem feito nas outras. Mas como  foi dito nos comentários pelo @PapaCharlie você poderia criar um
Helper e utilizá-lo para fazer isso. [Este link](http://www.dicascodeigniter.com.br/criando-seu-proprio-helper-no-codeigniter-formatar-preco/) tem um exemplo de como criar um Helper, e você pode adaptá-lo de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Comment: Acho interessante não só colocar o link.